How to make objects appear on the map at a certain distance based on scale?
Mode7 - Sprites on Screen / Pseudo 3D

Scale x1:


Scale x16:

I'm trying to recreate this system with JAVASCRIPT:
https://github.com/vinibiavatti1/Mode7/blob/master/src/mode7/FlatModeSeven.java
The result was this:


var pal = ["880015","5E000E","B7001C"];
var pTexture = [
0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,
2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
];
var textureW = 8;
var textureH = 8;
var ctx, canvasW, canvasH, centerH;

var qPI = 0.7853981633974483; // 45 degrees
var p_angle = qPI*7; // FaceUP in Game

var scaleX, scaleY, scaleLmt, camX, camY;

var control = {};

function Main() {
    // Initial Scale
    scaleX = 1;
    scaleY = 1;
    scaleLmt = scaleX*300; // Limiter for testing
    
    camX = 15; //(textureW*2)+8;
    camY = 15; //-((textureH*2)+8);
    
    var canvas = document.getElementById("screen");
    canvasW = canvas.width;
    canvasH = canvas.height;
    centerH = canvasH/2;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "yellow"; //Background color
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasW, canvasH); // Draw background    

    document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
        control[e.keyCode] = 1;
    });

    document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
        control[e.keyCode] = 0;
    });
    
    document.body.addEventListener('wheel', function(e){
        if (e.deltaY < 0) {
            scaleX += 0.2;
            scaleY += 0.2;
        }
        if (e.deltaY > 0) {
            scaleX -= 0.2;
            scaleY -= 0.2;
        }
    });
    
    setInterval(Render,60);
}

function Render() {
    var p, y2, x2;
    var cos = Math.cos(p_angle);
    var sin = Math.sin(p_angle);
    var z = 1;
    
    if (scaleX < 1) {
        scaleX = 1;
    }
    if (scaleY < 1) {
        scaleY = 1;
    }
    if (scaleX > scaleLmt) {
        scaleX = scaleLmt;
    }
    if (scaleY > scaleLmt) {
        scaleY = scaleLmt;
    }
    for (y = centerH; y < canvasH; y++) {
        for (x = 0;x < canvasW;x++) {
            y2 = ((canvasW - x) * cos - x * sin) / z;
            x2 = ((canvasW - x) * sin + x * cos) / z;
            if (z < 0) {
                x2 -= (camX/scaleX);
                y2 -= (camY/scaleY);
            } else {
                x2 += (camX/scaleX);
                y2 += (camY/scaleY);
            }
            if (y2 < 0) {
                y2 *= -1;
            }
            if (x2 < 0) {
                x2 *= -1;
            }
            y2 *= scaleY;
            x2 *= scaleX;

            x2 %= textureW;
            y2 %= textureH;
            
            p = pTexture[(Math.floor(x2) + Math.floor(y2) * textureW)];
            ctx.fillStyle = "#"+pal[p];
            ctx.fillRect(x,y, 1,1);
        }
        z++;
    }
    
    // CONTROL
    if (control["87"]) {
        /*W*/
        camX += Math.sin(p_angle + qPI) //* (scaleX*2);
        camY += Math.cos(p_angle + qPI) //* (scaleY*2);
    }
    if (control["83"]) {
        /*S*/
        camX -= Math.sin(p_angle + qPI) //* (scaleX*2);
        camY -= Math.cos(p_angle + qPI) //* (scaleY*2);
    }
    if (control["65"]) {
        /*A*/
        p_angle -= 0.1;
    }
    if (control["68"]) {
        /*D*/
        p_angle += 0.1;
    }
    if (control["38"]) {
        /*ArrowUp*/
        scaleY += 2;
    }
    if (control["40"]) {
        /*ArrowDown*/
        scaleY -= 2;
    }
    if (control["37"]) {
        /*ArrowLeft*/
        scaleX += 2;
    }
    if (control["39"]) {
        /*ArrowRight*/
        scaleX -= 2;
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    Main()
});
<canvas id="screen" width="320", height="180"></canvas>
<pre>Forward: W | Back: S | Rotate Left: A | Rotate Right: D
WheelUp: Further (Scale) | WheelDown : Closer (Scale)
ArrowUP/ArrowDow : Further (ScaleY)
ArrowLeft/ArrowRight : Further (ScaleX)</pre>



However, I can't think of a way to make objects appear on the map at a certain distance based on scale.
https://www.coranac.com/tonc/text/mode7ex.htm
It would be something like this, but I'm still having trouble getting this to work with rotation:
/* Draw Sprites */
for (let s in sprites) {
    let deltaX = sprites[s].x - camX;
    let deltaY = sprites[s].y - camY;

    let dxx = cos / scaleX;
    let dyx = sin / scaleY;
    let dxy = -sin / scaleX;
    let dyy = cos / scaleY;
    let dx = sprites[s].x/textureW;
    let dy = sprites[s].y/textureH;

    let posX = dxx * deltaX + dyx * deltaY + dx;
    let posY = dxy * deltaX + dyy * deltaY + dy;

    ctx.fillStyle = "Blue";
    ctx.fillRect(posX,posY,16,16);
}

I've read several tutorials about RayCasting, but nothing seems to work well with this method that I'm already using.
One of the ones I tried was this:
https://github.com/catmanjan/mode-7-gdx/blob/master/core/src/au/com/twosquared/mode7/Mode7.java#L74
The closest solution I found was this, but I don't know if I could convert something made in Game Maker to pure Javascript:
https://mrlevrocks.itch.io/mode7/devlog/812974/how-to-add-billboards-to-mode-7-shader
https://jdiemke.github.io/aisa/mode-7.html

It's still difficult for me to understand what "make objects appear on the map at a certain distance based on scale" means here. An image of what you want, contrasted against an image of what you have, could be a big help. The links you've shared are long documents describing many aspects of the solution, so a reader will need you to narrow down more specifically what parts you need help with or what specifically is going wrong when you try to follow these guides.

I have included some images, although there are several examples of Pseudo 3D in different languages ​​and even tutorials, most of them do not explain very clearly how I can draw static objects like billboards in Canvas, I found examples with RayCast, but none of them make much sense with changed scale

What should a reader learn from these images? Is this what your app generates currently, or what you want it to generate? What is good or bad about what's in the images? Remember that we know nothing about your project except what you explicitly explain in your text, so don't assume that what's obvious to you will be equally obvious to a reader.

I apologize for the lack of details about the goal and how it should work. The sprites on the screen will be read from a list and most of them will be the same size, but instead of drawing pixel by pixel I think it would be faster to draw the image in the exact size and position, I used only simple rectangles because the focus is to try to understand the algorithm that remembers and positions them correctly. The idea is to create an overworld to access cities in a simple adventure game, like an RPG and maybe in the future to create a racing or exploration game.
